# Clone record in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149792/1077789) answer comes close to what I need but my situation is slightly different. I have a SQL table look like this.

```
+------+----------+-----------+
|  aid |  afname  |  alname   |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  01  |  John    |  Doe      |
|  02  |  Stephen |  Williams |
|  03  |  Jane    |  Doe      |
|  04  |  Peter   |  Brown    |
|  05  |          |           |
+------+----------+-----------+
```

Now I need to clone/copy only the `afname` and `alname` fields from the row which has the **02** `aid` and insert it into the row with the `aid` **05**.

This is the query I tried but it throws an Syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO table1(afname, alname) 
WHERE aid = '05'
SELECT afname, alname
FROM table1
WHERE aid = '02'
```

Can anyone please tell me a way to accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a row with `aid` = '05' :

```
INSERT INTO table1(aid,afname, alname)
SELECT '05', afname, alname
FROM table1
WHERE aid = '02'
```

If you have a row with `aid` = '05' and you want to update it :

```
update t2
set t2.afname = t1.afname, t2.alname = t1.alname
from table1 t1 join table1 t2 on t1.aid = '02' and t2.aid = '05'
```

Comment: The second method is what I needed. Thanks a lot Grisha :)