# How do you copy a row in a SQL table and alter one of the column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149784/how-do-you-copy-a-record-in-a-sql-table-but-swap-out-the-unique-id-of-the-new-ro) almost answer mine, but not quite. How do I turn this:

```
col0  col1 col2
data0 a    foo
data1 b    foo
data2 c    fee
data3 d    fee
```

into this? (duplicating the `foo` rows only)

```
col0  col1 col2
data0 a    foo
data1 b    foo
data2 c    fee
data3 d    fee
data0 a    bar
data1 b    bar
```

Where `bar` is from the statement, not the data, and the original table has 2 new rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into T (col0, col1, col2)
select col0, col1, 'bar'
from T
```

If by "copy" you mean a `select` then a union would work as in other answers or you could try this:

```
select col0, col1, case when num = 0 then col2 else 'bar' end as col2
from T, (select 0 as num union all select 1) as dup
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, `union all`:

```
select col0, col1, col2
from yourtable
union all
select col0, col1, 'bar'
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just wanted the results for these two hard-coded strings, the following query would provide that for you.

```
    SELECT
        col0,
        col1,
        'foo'
    FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        col0,
        col1,
        'bar'
    FROM MyTable;
```

A more practical scenario is to use a temp table so you're not duplicating your query for each scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE #Options
(
    col2 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #Options VALUES ('foo'), ('bar');

SELECT
    col0,
    col1,
    #Options.col2
FROM MyTable
CROSS JOIN #Options;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col0, col1, col2
from yourtable
union all
select col0, col1, 'bar'
from yourtable
where col2 = 'foo'
```