# MySQL query to filter records and duplicate each record with another value in the filtered field

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL table has a field with a category for each project. Now I need to filter for instance all records with cat_id 34 and duplicate them with cat_id 30 (like the first record in the screenshot)
[Screenshot of records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZFHr.jpg)
Also included a screenshot with the structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yFfO.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149784/how-do-you-copy-a-record-in-a-sql-table-but-swap-out-the-unique-id-of-the-new-ro

Check this answer

Comment: Tried SELECT * FROM `aaa_advportfoliopro_projectcat_map` WHERE cat_id=34
INSERT INTO aaa_advportfoliopro_projectcat_map (project_id,cat_id)
VALUES (project_id,30) but doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Solved:INSERT INTO aaa_advportfoliopro_projectcat_map (project_id, cat_id, ordering, language)
SELECT project_id, (cat_id - 4), ordering, language 
  FROM aaa_advportfoliopro_projectcat_map
WHERE cat_id = "34"