# How can I copy rows from one to another table with a different number of columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a "unusual" problem on MySQL Syntax.

I have 2 tables:

> table1: commodityAttributes and has **7** column
> `id`,`id_commodity`,`parameter`,`value`,`units`,`type`,`notes`
>
> table2: trade_commodity and has **8** column
> `id`,`id_trade`,`id_commodity`,`parameter`,`value`,`units`,`type`,`notes`

**note: primary key for both tables are 'id', which is I didn't want to copy**

What I want, is copy all column from table1 to table2 but also create value for `id_trade` in table2.

Please take a look that table1 and table2 has different number of columns and `id_trade` on table2 IS NOT auto_increment.

Here is the example of the actual result and desired result:

```
table1: 
id,id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes 
1, 1, 'Ash','10','%','min','ash for a commodity' 
2, 1, 'Ash 2','15','%','max','ash for a commodity'
```

after do copy procedure, it produce:

```
table2:
id,id_trade,id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes 
1,NULL,1, 'Ash','10','%','min','ash for a commodity' 
2,NULL,1, 'Ash 2','15','%','max','ash for a commodity'
```

what I want is the result of table2:

```
id,id_trade,id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes
1,10,1, 'Ash','10','%','min','ash for a commodity'
2,10,1, 'Ash 2','15','%','max','ash for a commodity'
```

which is `'10'` for id_trade comes from php var.

How can I accomplish this? Or is there another tricky?
Btw, I am using PHP and MySQL to work on this task.

EDIT:
I see the "similiar" problem with this, but I found that he is trying to use command rather than value
[MYSQL: How to copy an entire row from one table to another in mysql with the second table having one extra column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353733/mysql-how-to-copy-an-entire-row-from-one-table-to-another-in-mysql-with-the-sec?rq=1)

Please kind help me, thank you.

Comment: How would you calculate the id_trade for any given row of table1?

Comment: so the value '10' for id_trade is common for all the rows of table 2?

Comment: @Maximus2012 yes. that's right!

Comment: ok...see the updated answer and see if that helps.

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee the value of `id_trade` comes from PHP variable and sometimes can be specified with constant value I given to program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
insert into table2 (id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes)
select id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes
from table1
```

UPDATE: In light of additional information provided by the OP, this should be the solution that the OP is looking for:

```
insert into table2 (id_trade, id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes)
select '10', id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes
from table1
```

Comment: He said he wants to create a value for id_trade (which is not the PK, thus is also not AUTO INCREMENT).

Comment: I have tried that code, but the result give null on table2.id_trade

Comment: this code will take care of auto_increment for id_trade if it is declared as an auto increment field at the time of table creation.

Comment: @PedroCordeiro Non-PK columns can be `auto_increment` they just need to have an index

Comment: @Matthew, I did not know that. That should do the trick then.

Comment: @dika46 the id_trade column of table2 needs to be defined as auto increment along with PK.

Comment: table2.id_trade is not auto_increment.

Comment: then what values do you want for table2.id_trade? Note that this is the only way to do it using MySQL only. If you want custom values then you need to write additional code using PHP/MySQL. If you could give an example of what do you want your table2 to look like then we can provide some suggestions for it.

Comment: @Maximus2012, table2.id_trade will be filled with value from PHP variable.

Comment: do you have some sample values for that variable ? Is it a constant ?

Comment: @Maximus2012

table1:
id,id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes
1, 1, 'Ash','10','%','min','ash for a commodity'
2, 1, 'Ash 2','15','%','max','ash for a commodity'

after do copy procedure, it produce:
id,id_trade,id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes
1,NULL,1, 'Ash','10','%','min','ash for a commodity'
2,NULL,1, 'Ash 2','15','%','max','ash for a commodity'

what I want is the result of table2:
id,id_trade,id_commodity,parameter,value,units,type,notes
1,10,1, 'Ash','10','%','min','ash for a commodity'
2,10,1, 'Ash 2','15','%','max','ash for a commodity'

10 comes from php var

Comment: @Maximus2012 doesn't work. it says, "Unknown column '10' in field list"