# MySQL trigger to copy all field values to another table, how?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 identical table (100% identical),

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
TRIGGER `db`.`new_user` AFTER INSERT
ON `db`.`user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO db2.`users` COPY ALL INSERTED DATA
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

How should the INSER query look like? Do I have to specifiy all field names one by one?

Comment: Either explicitly mention each column in the `VALUES` clause of the `INSERT` statement, or else use `INSERT ... SELECT` whilst filtering on the `NEW.primary_key`.

Comment: This is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168/how-to-copy-a-row-from-one-sql-server-table-to-another provides a great answer

Answer (score 2):

Since `NEW` is not a row identifier but rather a syntactic way for referring to particular columns in a row being manipulated by a trigger, you need to specify column names

```
INSERT INTO db2.`users` VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.username, ...);
```