# MySQL trigger INSERT all NEW columns

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

Is it possible to trigger the insert of all the columns for the NEW row? Basically, I want to make a copy of the newly insert record in another table but what having to specify all the columns.

Something like

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger
AFTER INSERT
   ON Table1 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `Table2` SELECT * FROM NEW;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However this returns `Table 'Database.NEW' doesn't exist` whenever I try to insert a new row in `Table1`.

[From MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html):

> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

Comment: @lad2025 That doesn't work MySQL returns "Cannot find table DatabaseName.NEW"

Comment: Anyway specify all column names manually because `SELECT *` is bad practice 9/10 cases

Comment: I actually disagree. I keep seeing people say doing x is a bad practice but x exists to be used and just because some people abuse doesn't mean it's bad practice. `SELECT *` is exactly what you should use if you do want **ALL** the columns

Comment: @Arijoon Thank you for your comment. Please see the edited question

Comment: is `NEW` a row or a table name? It has to be a table name. `SELECT <columns> table_name` is the right syntax and only supports table names

Comment: @Arijoon No it's not. I am referring to the newly inserted row. I edited the post with more information

Comment: `SELECT` is used to grab rows with matching columns or `*`. You do not need `SELECT` since you already have your row

Comment: @Arijoon I understand that but `INSERT INTO Table2 NEW` is syntactically incorrect. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354132/insert-data-into-table-with-result-from-another-select-query

Answer (score 2):

Despite the time this question have been unanswered, you can `SELECT` all fields using primary key in source table if you have one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER replicated_table AFTER INSERT ON source_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO replicated_table SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE id=NEW.id;
END
```

Also, maybe you can prefer the use of `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT` to ensure the table will not stay out of sincronization.

Comment: There is almost same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419227/mysql-trigger-to-copy-all-field-values-to-another-table-how and same solution could be applied